# R ggplot2 autoplot() function. What's wrong?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series, timeserieschart

I have a dataset "bc" with 2285 observations two variables: "Date" and "Price".

```
 'data.frame':  2285 obs. of  2 variables:
  $ Date : Date, format: "2017-12-14" "2017-12-13" ...
  $ Price: num  16234 16250 16650 16470 14691 ...
```

I tried to create a time series object as:

```
  tsbc <- ts(bc)
```

Then, I used:

```
  autoplot(tsbc)
```

And I get figure below:
[image: Plot-Image]
However, the plot is not how it is supposed to be. Could you help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `xts`:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Generate a dataset
set.seed(1)
bc <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2016/1/1"), as.Date("2017/12/14"), "days"),
                 Price= cumsum(rnorm(714)))
#   'data.frame':   714 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Date : Date, format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" ...
# $ Price: num  -0.626 -0.443 -1.278 0.317 0.646 ...

library(xts)
tsbc <- xts(bc$Price, order.by=bc$Date)
autoplot(tsbc)
```

[image]

Otherwise, using `ts`:

```
tsbc <- ts(bc$Price, start=c(2016,1), frequency=365)
autoplot(tsbc) + scale_x_yearmon(n=5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you created that time series object `tsbc`. You are actually creating two time series. And since dates are just numbers under the hood with a class attribute, they lose their attribute when you call `ts`. That's why `autoplot` draws a line for `Date` as well which plots the doubles representing the respective date (see `?base::Dates` for more details). Which is obviously not what you want. See @Marco's answer for how to construct the `ts` object.

However, you don't even need to do that. Why not simply

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bc, aes(Date, Price)) + geom_line()
```